# Cannot customise borders of years section in showDatePicker

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter  3.16.5.

The years section in the showDatePicker has a border top and bottom that cannot be customised and doesn't respond to any changes applied in the Theme.

I would expect that the dividerColor is also applied to this border, or that any other colours options in the ColorScheme could impact these borders. How can I change change the colours of these borders or if possible remove them altogether?

```
showDatePicker(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
      return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          inputDecorationTheme:
              InputDecorationTheme(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              width: 0.5,
              color: ColorRes.colorPrimary,
            ),
          )),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              onPrimary: ColorRes.white,
              primary: ColorRes.colorPrimary,
              background: ColorRes.white),
          datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData(
            headerBackgroundColor:
                ColorRes.colorPrimary,
            backgroundColor: ColorRes.white,
            headerForegroundColor: ColorRes.white,
            surfaceTintColor: ColorRes.white,
            dividerColor: ColorRes.colorPrimary,
          ),
        ),
        child: child!,
      );
    },
    locale: currentDefaultSystemLocale == "nl_NL"
        ? Locale("nl", "NL")
        : Locale("en", "US"),
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
    lastDate: DateTime.now()
        .add(const Duration(days: 183)))
```

[image: issue]

Comment: Yes, they still persist. I am thinking maybe it could be something related to the Theme settings from main.dart, but this is how that looks like. Also no impact if i change these values to white.

ThemeData(
            dialogBackgroundColor: ColorRes.white,
            dividerColor: ColorRes.colorBgGray,
            primaryColor: ColorRes.colorPrimary,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: ColorRes.colorPrimary, background: ColorRes.white)
        )

Comment: Yeah I looked at the wrong place before. I also have them. That's why I deleted my previous comment. Although mine are more grey and not as black as yours. I guess it's something in the main theme data that controls it

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing the outlineVariant in the colorScheme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I've digged more into it and I found this documentation in the Divider class

```
  /// If [color] is null, then [DividerThemeData.color] is used. If that is also
  /// null, then if [ThemeData.useMaterial3] is true then it defaults to
  /// [ThemeData.colorScheme]'s [ColorScheme.outlineVariant]. Otherwise
  /// [ThemeData.dividerColor] is used.
```

The date picker uses two Dividers without color argument so, according to the documentation, if you have in your `ThemeData` a `dividerTheme` defined it will use the color in that regardles whether you have `useMaterial3` true or false. If you don't have a `dividerTheme` defined and you use `useMaterial3: false` it looks at the `dividerColor`. If you do have `useMaterial3: true` (which is the default in the latest Flutter version) it uses the `outlineVariant` of the `colorScheme`. Digging further I could see that if your `colorScheme` doesn't have a `outlineVariant` defined it defaults to the `colorScheme`'s `onBackground` which has `Colors.black` as default for the `ColorScheme.light` constructor. This is why it was black.